# How to update specific values in a column with other values from same column in the same table? - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

So lets say I have a Table "Stuff".
It has 3 columns.

[image: Table Details]

So Job Code is supposed to be the same for both manager and the employee under that manager(like it is where jobcode= 000 ). That is the normal scenario.
However in some cases, The Manager will have "ABC" as jobcode.
In those cases, I need to replace "ABC" with the jobcode value of the most recent employee under that manager.
For example, for Manager A1, I need to replace his jobcode of ABC with 234,considering B1 is the most recent employee under him.
For manager A, his jobcode of ABC will be replaced with 121 since B is the only employee under him.

I wrote this query but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Update X

Set X.JobCode=Y.JobCode

FROM STUFF X

INNER JOIN STUFF Y

ON X.MGRCODE=Y.MGRCODE

AND X.JOBCODE = 'ABC"

AND Y.JOBCODE = ( SELECT TOP 1 JOBCODE FROM STUFF WHERE EMPCODE<>Y.MGRCODE AND
Y.MGRCODE IN (SELECT MGRCODE FROM STUFF WHERE EMPCODE=MGRCODE AND JOBCODE='ABC')
```

Comment: what version of sql server? You can use `LEAD` or a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` for this. Also when using `TOP` you need an `ORDER BY` to make it deterministic

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2.
And yes there is an updatedate which I use with the order by clause.
And I was wondering whether there was any way to do this with a simple query and joins?

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cteJobCodeRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       ManagerCode
       ,JobCode
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ManagerCode ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) as RowNumber
    FROM
       @Table
)

UPDATE t
    SET JobCode = r.JobCode
FROM
    @Table t
    INNER JOIN cteJobCodeRowNum r
    ON t.EmpCode = r.ManagerCode
    AND r.RowNumber = 1
    AND t.JobCode <> r.JobCode
WHERE
    t.JobCode = 'ABC'
```

Use a partitioned window function to generate a Row Number to choose the Job Code you want.  Partition by `ManagerCode` and order by `UpdateDate` descending.  Then join that common table expression (or derived table if you nest it) to your table based on `EmpCode` = `ManagerCode` To Update The Managers record.  You can also then constrain it only to when the Manager has a Job Code of 'ABC' and the job code returned by the row number is different so you only update a specific set of rows.

Another similar method is to create your own row number by using a related cross apply such as:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET JobCode = NewJobCode
FROM
    @Table t1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 JobCode as NewJobCode FROM @Table t2 WHERE t1.EmpCode = t2.ManagerCode ORDER BY t2.UpdateDate DESC) n
WHERE
    t1.JobCode = 'ABC'
    AND t1.JobCode <> n.NewJobCode
```

Here is a full working example of the window function method:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (JobCode CHAR(3), EmpCode VARCHAR(2), ManagerCode VARCHAR(2), UpdateDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Table (JobCode, EmpCode, ManagerCode, UpdateDate)
VALUES ('ABC','A','A',GETDATE()-1),('121','B','B',GETDATE()-1)
,('ABC','A1','A1',GETDATE()-1)
,('234','B1','A1',GETDATE()+1)
,('342','C1','A1',GETDATE()-1)
,('000','A2','A2',GETDATE()-1)
,('000','B2','B2',GETDATE()-1)

SELECT *
FROM
    @Table

;WITH cteJobCodeRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       ManagerCode
       ,JobCode
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ManagerCode ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) as RowNumber
    FROM
       @Table
)

UPDATE t
    SET JobCode = r.JobCode
FROM
    @Table t
    INNER JOIN cteJobCodeRowNum r
    ON t.EmpCode = r.ManagerCode
    AND r.RowNumber = 1
    AND t.JobCode <> r.JobCode
WHERE
    t.JobCode = 'ABC'


SELECT *
FROM
    @Table
```

Comment: Hmm this kind of worked. The cte solution was really good. Thank you :)